# Aromatic firewood: What is the fastest growing prunus plant?

Tags: fruit-trees, cherries, peaches, plums, apricots

***Prunus*** firewood smells nice when burned, and the smoke can be used to flavour food (it adds a cherry-like flavour).

[image]

I'm curious if it would be feasible to grow *prunus* plants specifically for using the wood as aromatic firewood.

What is the **fastest growing** ***prunus*** plant that is hardy to USDA zone 5?

Comment: I'm east of Toronto.

Comment: Note that, Included in in the genus Prunus is Prunus laurocerasus and its cultivars, and they are fast growing - it is not recommended that this plant is burned, especially  not in a closed space, and it should not be used to smoke foods because it can produce toxic smoke.

Comment: @Bamboo : Oh. I had no idea. Good to know.

Comment: @Bamboo That is good to know!!!! Good work.

Comment: I don't know about the fastest, but the biggest ones we've grown were apricots. I imagine they were the fastest we've grown, too, but I can't say. Peaches are fairly fast.

Answer (score 2):

Black Cherry [(*Prunus serotina*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_serotina) is the best one where I am, because it's relatively fast growing (splittable wood every 12/18 years in decent conditions, and can be [coppiced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppicing). The favorable smoke fragrance is very good with this species.

It is hardy in zone 5.